# How to show fields from an ArcGIS Online feature layer in a popup using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

For example for this link: https://services5.arcgis.com/XqaKEQIgV03geG0E/arcgis/rest/services/24hour_Clinics/FeatureServer/20

I want to make pop out appear on javascript. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to enable default popup templates for your layers:

```
view.popup.defaultPopupTemplateEnabled = true;
```

See the following CodePen for a live demo: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/ddf9a71a85ec46fd291e38c8cc259fd6?editors=1010

You can also define customized popups by setting [`FeatureLayer.popupTemplate`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#popupTemplate), see [PopupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html) for samples and more information.